# Points to path segments

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance, linear-referencing

I have a point shape (ID, value) which I have converted to a path (points to path). Is it possible to get the lines between each point? The picture below shows what I mean. The colored path is what I want to get.

Is there a tool or workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing script in the **Online scripts collection** for the *Processing* plugin called ["Distance lines between points"](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/scripts/distance_lines_between_points.py) which uses an input point layer and creates an output line layer. The lines in the output layer are split between the points and contains only a distance field.

You can access this from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Get scripts from on-line scripts collection
```

One problem with the script is that it creates lines from each point to every other point which can cause overlaps. I've edited the code slightly by replacing the existing `if` statement (which avoids duplicates):

```
if feature1.id() < feature2.id():
```

with

```
if feature2.id() == feature1.id() + 1:
```

as this only creates lines from **one feature to the previous feature**, thus not creating **duplicates** or **overlaps**:

[image: Distance lines between points]

*Note: This will only work efficiently if the* `id()` *of each point is ordered correctly*.

---

Here is the full code:

```
##Distance lines between points=name
##Vector=group
##pointLayer=vector
##outputLayer=output vector

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter

inputLayer = processing.getObject(pointLayer)
# create new layer for output:
fields = [QgsField('distance', QVariant.Double)]
writer = VectorWriter(outputLayer, None, fields, QGis.WKBLineString, inputLayer.crs())
# loop all points:
iter1 = inputLayer.getFeatures()
for feature1 in iter1:
    p1 = feature1.geometry().asPoint()
    # loop all points again:
    iter2 = inputLayer.getFeatures()
    for feature2 in iter2:
        # following line creates lines from one feature to previous feature:
        if feature2.id() == feature1.id() + 1:
            # create new line feature:
            p2 = feature2.geometry().asPoint()
            l = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([p1,p2])
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat.setGeometry(l)
            feat.setAttributes([l.length()])
            writer.addFeature(feat)
del writer
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called `v.split.vert` in the GRASS section of the processing toolbox.

[image]

In the `Maximum number of vertices in segment` field, just put 2. This should create a new line layer with all your segments as separate features.

Comment: I tried this but maybe I've done a mistake with the points to path tool. The v.split.vert occures an error. When I want to create a line or path based on the points whicht tool is the best and what are the correct settings?

Comment: Sorry, you have to put 2 in the "Maximum number of vertices..." field. I updated my answer.