# Measuring between points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, measurements

I'm trying to automatically measure the distance between 500 points in order of attribute value. So the points have the value 1 to 500 and in that order I want to measure the individual distance of all points from its predecessor.

Is there a tool or plugin to execute this analysis in QGIS?

Comment: Can you give the "geographical" definition of _"distance from its predecessor "_ ... is it the closest point ? or do u have any information in your attribute table to determine the **points sequence**  ?

Comment: There  is a value in the attribute table with the route of the points where the first point is 1 and the last 500

Comment: @GeoMediaanddesign - Do the attribute values match the order the points were created? I.e. the 100th point added has the value 100?

Comment: Yes the 100th point has the value of point 100

Comment: @GeoMediaanddesign - There is a script mentioned in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207290/points-to-path-segments) which creates lines between points (with respect to their creation id). You could then use the **Field Calculator** on this line layer to calculate the distance of each line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a plugin for that.  But with a little sql, you can calculate it.

If predecessor is defined by their id, then you can execute following code in the databasemanager:

```
select
a. id, 
b. id predecessor,
st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) distance
from fictief_point a 
left join fictief_point b on a.id-1 = b.id
```

Go to Database > DB manager > DB manager.  Navigate to QGIS layers and select your layer.

Open an sql-window and paste above code.  Change 'fictief_point' twice to your layer name.

[image]